# Can the java compiler optimize loops to return early?

Tags: java, performance, jit

I'm working with an external library that decided to handle collections on its own. Not working with it or updating is outside my control. To work with elements of this third party "collection" it only returns iterators.

A question came up during a code review about having multiple returns in the code to gain performance. We all agree (within the team) the code is more readable with a single return, but some are worried about optimizations.

I'm aware premature optimization is bad. That is a topic for another day.

I believe the JIT compiler can handle this and skip the unneeded iterations, but could not find any info to back this up. **Is JIT capable of such a thing?**

A code sample of the issue at hand:

```
public void boolean contains(MyThings things, String valueToFind) {
    Iterator<Thing> thingIterator = things.iterator();
    boolean valueFound = false;
    while(thingIterator.hasNext()) {
        Thing thing = thingIterator.next();
        if (valueToFind.equals(thing.getValue())) {
            valueFound = true;
        }
    }
    return valueFound;
}
```

VS

```
public void boolean contains(MyThings things, String valueToFind) {
    Iterator<Thing> thingIterator = things.iterator();
    while(thingIterator.hasNext()) {
        Thing thing = thingIterator.next();
        if (valueToFind.equals(thing.getValue())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use a `break` inside the `while` loop? But I'm pretty sure the compiler will **not** terminate the loop early in the first example. How should it know that the following iterations  are no longer needed?

Comment: Those two examples don't even have the same behavior. The first one will return whether the last element of the collection is equal to `valueToFind`, while the second one returns whether `valueToFind` is anywhere in the collection.

Comment: yes in the sample code it can be seen that a break would remove unnecessary iterations.

Comment: I doubt that it would do that. `valueFound = valueToFind.equals(thing.getValue());` has potential side-effects that the compiler would try to avoid suppressing.

Comment: I would highly doubt that the JIT compiler would do such a thing since it compiles based on methods and number of times methods are called.

Comment: Multiple returns would have negligible impact on performance if any. Multiple returns can help improve readability, IMHO. You only have to read the method until you get to the exit you want as opposed to having to make sure the return value doesn’t get tweaked along the way. Now if you have a lot of return statements that’s more a problem of cohesion and you should be refactoring that method into something smaller.

Comment: Actually I don't like the `break` in Java code, but if you extract the loop into a function like `findValue` you can return at any time, and your code will be more readable :)

Comment: @OhleC thanks for pointing that out, I didn't pay close enough attention. I edited the question.

Answer (score 4):

> We all agree the code is more readable with a single return.

Not really. This is just old school structured programming when functions were typically not kept small and the paradigms of keeping values immutable weren't popular yet.

Although subject to debate, there is nothing wrong with having very small methods (a handful of lines of code), which return at different points. For example, in recursive methods, you typically have at least one base case which returns immediately, and another one which returns the value returned by the recursive call.

Often you will find that creating an extra result variable, just to hold the return value, and then making sure no other part of the function overwrites the result, when you already know you can just return, just creates noise which makes it less readable not more. The reader has to deal with cognitive overload to see the result is not modified further down. During debugging this increases the pain even more.

I don't think your example is premature optimisation. It is a logical and critical part of your search algorithm. That is why you can `break` from loops, or in your case, just return the value. I don't think the JIT could realise that easily it should break out the loop. It doesn't know if you want to change the variable back to `false` if you find something else in the collection. (I don't think it is that smart to realise that `valueFound` doesn't change back to `false`).

In my opinion, your second example is not only more readable (the `valueFound` variable is just extra noise) but also faster, because it just returns when it does its job. The first example would be as fast if you put a `break` after setting `valueFound = true`. If you don't do this, and you have a million items to check, and the item you need is the first, you will be comparing all the others just for nothing.

Comment: Edited the question to clarify the agreement is within the team working with the library.

Comment: @PaulDaPigeon sure, just saying that this agreement within your team could be outdated.

Answer (score 1):

Java compiler cannot do an optimization like that, because doing so in a general case would change the logic of the program.

Specifically, adding an early return would change the number of invocations of `thingIterator.hasNext()`, because your first code block continues iterating the collection to the end.

Java could potentially replace a `break` with an early return, but that would have any effect on the timing of the program.